# How to add a theme attribute to android:startColor in gradient drawable in Android?

Tags: android, android-layout

According to android documentation, android:startColor can take attributes as a value:

> This may also be a reference to a resource (in the form
>   "@[package:]type:name") or theme attribute (in the form
>   "?[package:][type:]name") containing a value of this type.

I am trying to add an attribute to my gradiant drawable, however I get an error. Here is the code for the drawable:

Here is the code in style.xml:

```
<style name="test" parent="android:Theme">
    <item name="android:startColor">#0b2749</item> 
    <item name="startColor">#0b2749</item>
</style>
```

When I try to run the activity I get this error message:

```
01-10 20:47:30.810: E/AndroidRuntime(7279): Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Can't convert to color: type=0x2
```

I tried changing ?startColor to ?attr/startColor and still got the same error. I also applied the theme to the activity in the AndroidManifest.xml file.

How can I add a theme attribute to the gradient drawable?

Comment: Same problem here with android:color on a stroke element. In fact, it looks like this exception occurs each time we try to reference a style attribute from a drawable. This looks like an Android bug.

Comment: I found a workaround that may work for you, see my answer

Answer (score 3):

I was having the same problem in one of my drawable in which I want different colors based on the chosen theme. I found a workaround, that doesn't exactly solve the problem, but works for me. Instead of defining the color in my styles, I define the whole drawable as a reference.

In `attrs.xml`:

```
<resources>
    <attr name="myDrawable" format="reference"/>
<resources>
```

And in my `style.xml`:

```
<style name="style1">
    <item name="myDrawable">@drawable/myDrawable1</item>
<style>
<style name="style2">
    <item name="myDrawable">@drawable/myDrawable2</item>
<style>
```

Of course, you need to define two drawables in your drawable folder, `myDrawable1` and `myDrawable2`, each one having the correct color hard-coded.

And it works fine.

Comment: Thank you. I am aware of this solution, and the reason that I wanted to solve through attributes to decrease the number of drawables that I have in my application to keep it manageable since they already too much.

Comment: Yes I have the same concern, that's why I call that a workaround only. I'm still interested in finding a real solution too, though I begin to doubt there isone, it seems more and more like an Android bug, or feature...

Comment: Also, the fact that we can't have subfolders in the drawable folder is a pain for medium to large projects (I have 5000+ items in one of my projects...)

Comment: Subfolders issue can be overcome by using the right naming convention like: folder_file_or_drawable_name.xml.

Answer (score 0):

```
<style name="customTheme" parent="android:Theme">  
    <item name="android:windowTitleBackgroundStyle">@style/WindowTitleBackground</item>
</style>
```

Add the above code in colors.xml in values folder and the following code in styles.xml

```
<color name="titlebackgroundcolor">#FFFFFF</color>
<color name="titletextcolor">#000000</color>
```

Comment: Code is unclear. Would you please format it so I would be able to test it.

Comment: Just add < and > tags at style and item, I could not put it as it was making the text invisible

Comment: <style name="customTheme" parent="android:Theme">

<item> name="android:windowTitleBackgroundStyle"@style/WindowTitleBackground </item>

</style>

Add the above code in colors.xml in values folder and the following code in styles.xml

<color name="titlebackgroundcolor">  #FFFFFF  </color>

<color name="titletextcolor"> #000000  </color>

Comment: How would I apply this to gradient drawable?

Answer (score -1):

Looks like you just made a small mistake for your color.
Android takes the `#[alpha] [hex]` type of input for colors. You just provided the hex part. 
Android doesn't support this, hence the `UnsupportedOperationException`.

Try using this:

`<item name="android:startColor">#FF0b2749</item>`

I can't guarantee that this works though, as I have never worked with gradients in combination with a style.

Comment: Actually android supports colors without the alpha value. According to the same documentation:     Must be a color value, in the form of "#rgb", "#argb", "#rrggbb", or "#aarrggbb".

Comment: Hmm. The more you know.
Had problems with this a while ago until I added alpha but good to know it works without.

Comment: That doesn't solve the problem, though: with or without the alpha value, the same exception occurs